# Copy as curl with help of selenium

Tags: c++, multithreading, atomic

I am solving leetcode task https://leetcode.com/problems/print-foobar-alternately/

I have two solutions
The first -- OK (passed tests)
I used condition_variable to synchronize threads.

```
// First
class FooBar {
private:
    int n;
    condition_variable cv_;
    int iteration_;
    mutex m_;

public:
    FooBar(int n) {
        this->n = n;
        iteration_ = 0;
    }

    void foo(function<void()> printFoo) {
        unique_lock<mutex> lock(m_);
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            cv_.wait(lock, [&] {return iteration_ % 2 == 0;});
            // printFoo() outputs "foo". Do not change or remove this line.
            printFoo();
            iteration_++;
            cv_.notify_all();
        }
    }

    void bar(function<void()> printBar) {
        unique_lock<mutex> lock(m_);
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            cv_.wait(lock, [&] {return iteration_ % 2 == 1;});
            // printBar() outputs "bar". Do not change or remove this line.
            printBar();
            iteration_++;
            cv_.notify_all();
        }
    }
};
```

But the second (based on std::atomic) has Time Limit Exceed error.

Could you please explain wht the second solution is slow?

```
class FooBar {
private:
    int n;
    atomic<bool> is_foo = true;

public:
    FooBar(int n) {
        this->n = n;
    }

    void foo(function<void()> printFoo) {
        
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            while(!is_foo);
            // printFoo() outputs "foo". Do not change or remove this line.
            printFoo();
            is_foo = false;
        }
    }

    void bar(function<void()> printBar) {
        
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            while(is_foo);
            // printBar() outputs "bar". Do not change or remove this line.
            printBar();
            is_foo = true;
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Try adding std::this_thread::sleep_for() like this: while(is_foo) { std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(2)); }

Answer (score 0):

Atomic variables are not synchronisation primitives, they don't put executing threads to sleep or wake other threads up. `while(!is_foo);` and `while(is_foo);` in each thread get so much time for executions how much the OS scheduler allows, not switching to another thread. The CPU consumption reaches 100%.
It may be resolved by switching to another thread if the condition is not met.

```
while(!is_foo)
  std::this_thread::yield();
```

```
while(is_foo)
  std::this_thread::yield();
```